# How do you distinguish between a participle and a gerund in a modifying phrase?

Tags: grammar

I'm taking the Poynter Institute's Language Primer course and was confused by the following passage:

> A modifying phrase can contain
>
> A participle: Being very hungry, …
>
> A gerund: Working all day, …
>
> Or an infinitive: To prepare for her presentation, …

The full examples appear later in the text:

> Being very hungry, I thought the quiche looked delicious.

> Working all day, I get sweaty and find a shower refreshing.

I believe the main difference between a participle and a gerund is that a gerund functions like a noun, but I'm not sure how you would tell that the first example contains a participle while the second contains a gerund. Any thoughts?

Comment: Either of those _-ing_ phrases can be called either a participle or a gerund, since they're out of context. That's a poor textbook with badly chosen examples.

Comment: A classification of anything matters only if something depends on it. What depends on whether you label a particular instance of this form one way or the other?

Answer (score 2):

> Working all day, I get sweaty and find a shower refreshing.

In that example, "working" is still a participle; it's modifying "I." Your book appears to be wrong on this point. A true example of a gerund would be:

> I get sweaty **from** working all day.

In that sentence, the gerund "working" is indeed acting as a noun, serving as the objection of the preposition "from."

Answer (score 1):

'Functions like a noun' is a vague definition for a gerund, seeing as noun phrases can function as anything aside from the predicator (verb at the head of the clause).

> **Last Tuesday** was great!   [subject]
>
> **Last Tuesday**, we had a really long meeting.  [adjunct]
>
> Would you consider **this Tuesday** for the meeting?   [object]
>
> His only day off was **last Tuesday**.  [predicative complement]

Then if we were to consider that the function of a noun is typically head of a noun phrase, we'd see that there are only certain 'gerunds' that have the properties of a noun - can be modified by adjectives, take determiners, have plural forms, etc.

> This is [the best **solution** I can think of].
>
> *This is [the best **solving** I can think of].
>
> These are [the best **solutions** I can think of].
>
> *These are [the best **solvings** I can think of].
>
> This **solution's** price is a little too high.
>
> *This **solving's** price is a little too high.

The simplest solution to the problem is to throw out the notion of 'functions as a noun' and ask instead does it have the properties of a noun? If it has plural forms, can be modified by adjectives, can take a range of determiners, then it IS a noun.

> This crazy **training** is almost over.
>
> I'm attending two more **trainings** this week.
>
> The **training's** organizers need to be paid.

If, on the other hand, it takes dependents such as subjects, objects, adjuncts, predicative complements, or catenative complements like a verb would when it heads a clause, then it's a verb heading a clause.

> [Bob **trying** to get accepted as an apprentice last year] was bound
> to fail.

If it comes down to a single word, it may be ambiguous whether it's a noun heading a noun phrase or a verb heading a clause.

In the case of the examples provided, they're quite clearly participial clauses as they have the structure of a clause and could not take any of the dependents typical of a noun phrase.

> (1)Being (2)very hungry, I thought the quiche looked delicious.
>
> (1)Working (3)all day, I get sweaty and find a shower refreshing.
>
> (1) predicator - verb at the head of the clause
>
> (2) predicative complement
>
> (3) adjunct of duration
>
> ***The** being very hungry, I thought the quiche looked delicious.
>
> ***The** working all day, I get sweaty and find a shower refreshing.
>
> ***Constant** being very hungry, I thought the quiche looked
> delicious.
>
> ***Strenuous** working all day, I get sweaty and find a shower refreshing.

Replacing either one with a noun or a noun phrase would also fail.

> ***Myself** very hungry, I thought the quiche looked delicious.
>
> ***Hard work** all day, I get sweaty and find a shower refreshing.

Comment: How is the poss-ing ('Bob's painting his daughter was a joy to behold')  structure analysed per the above? The whole N ... V ing-classification has been argued over for decades and done to death on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Genitive NPs as subject of gerund-participial clauses are nothing extraordinary. Surprisingly, many are still thrown for a loop by anything with an -ing on it; a little research really would go a long way.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *It*-extraposition teases out the more customary construction here: *It was a joy to behold Bob painting his daughter.*